# Vim with colors on Mac command line?

Tags: macos, vim

Vim I used once on Linux has syntax coloring. But not in my Mac command line. How can I get syntax coloring? I have MacVim too, but I'm trying to adapt on command line.

I'm currently editing Haskell file on remote server via Vim installed locally. It'll be appreciated too if you guide me to get Haskell specific syntax coloring.

Answer (score 4):

Create .vimrc in your home directory, like so:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

Then paste this:

```
if has('syntax') && (&t_Co > 2)
  syntax on
endif
```

I believe vim on Snow Leopard (10.6+) supports haskell syntax out of the box.